# webkit transition delay not applying while i do change the class name

Tags: jquery, webkit

I am making a slide show, for that, i made a overlay to show, while the people click on the images in the list.

in the overlay div, i applied '1s' of delay in my opacity change. but when i change the class from hidden to show, i am not getting the day on opacity.

any good way to achieve this, or proper way to do this?

function:

```
var showOverlay = function(params){
    var layer = params.overlay;
    console.log(layer);
    if('layer:hidden'){
        layer.removeClass('hidden');
        layer.addClass('show');
    }
}

var basicLayout = function (params) {

    var $list = params.list;

    $list.click( function () {
        showOverlay(params);
    } );
}

$(document).ready( function () {
    var params = {
        list : $('#container').find('li'),
        overlay : $('#overlay')
    }
    basicLayout(params)
})​
```

[here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RhPhb/)

Answer (score 0):

The condition is wrong:

```
if ( layer.is(':hidden') ) {
```

Comment: till not working. even if this is not correct,('layer:hidden'), the class is applying right? once the new class applied, i am not getting the delay in transition

Answer (score 0):

with some experiment, i split my function to like this :

```
var showOverlay = function(params){
    var layer = params.overlay;

    if( layer.is(':hidden') ){
        layer.removeClass('hidden');//1
        layer.show();//2
        layer.addClass('show');//3 - applying separately, now it works fine.
    }
}

var basicLayout = function (params) {

    var $list = params.list;

    $list.click( function () {
        showOverlay(params);
    } );
}

$(document).ready( function () {
    var params = {
        list : $('#container').find('li'),
        overlay : $('#overlay')
    }
    basicLayout(params)
})
```

thanks all.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to `#overlay.show` and `#overlay.hidden` in your CSS. Instead set `#overlay` to `display: none` instead of `opacity: 0`.

Then remove:

```
if('layer:hidden'){
    layer.removeClass('hidden');
    layer.addClass('show');
}
```

and replace it with:

```
layer.fadeIn();
```

Or if you want a one second delay you can use:

```
layer.delay(1000).fadeIn();
```